# How did I get picked for a Careers 2.0 profile?

Tags: support, jobs, email

I just received the following email:

> In recognition of your contributions to Stack Overflow, we’d like to
>   invite you to create a professional profile on Stack Overflow Careers
>   2.0.
>
> A Careers 2.0 profile is a great place to showcase your professional
>   work as a programmer – Stack Exchange answers, open source projects,
>   even the books you’ve read.
>
> Click here to accept the invitation. It’s free!
>
> Even if you’re not looking for a new career today, your Careers 2.0
>   profile will be your professional home on the web. It lets your
>   colleagues, friends, and peers know who you are and what great work
>   you’re doing. It’s a terrific way to build your professional
>   reputation and take your career to the next level. And it’s fun!
>
> You’ll always have complete control over what’s in your profile, who
>   can see it, and whether or not employers can contact you.
>
> But please act soon: this invitation expires in 14 days, so sign up
>   now!
>
> Even if you decide not to join Careers 2.0, we would like to thank you
>   for all your contributions to Stack Overflow. It wouldn’t be the same
>   without you.
>
> Best wishes,
>
> The Stack Overflow team

I appreciate the account and while I'm not looking for a job I'll create a profile just to say I have one now. However I'm confused by how I was "chosen" for this. I haven't been contributing much to Stack Overflow recently, much more to MSO and Cog Sci. What triggered this email to me *now?*

Comment: Good question; as I recall, I got my invitation during a "lull" in my activity, as well.

Comment: You're *special*.

Comment: Thanks @casperOne. [I'm special!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zun7w.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We just adjusted some criteria for how these are awarded.  The exact criteria are secret, but the adjustment means that some accounts which were not previously eligible now are.

Comment: I love SEEKRETS. Especially the ones I know. :p

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Personally, I love SKEETKRETS the best

Comment: @cdeszaq Sure, so does everyone. But try saying that five times, fast!

Comment: I can't even say that *once*, LOL

Comment: @David Fullerton Could you confirm I understand correctly: The email is intended to create the impression of an exclusive club, some sort of elite, but SO refuses to say in what way it is exclusive? If so, can you say why the nature of the exclusivity is secret?

Comment: @fsb We won't say the exact numbers, because we don't want people to game it.  We're happy to talk about the *nature* of the exclusivity: demonstrate that you actually know something.  You can do that via SO, GitHub, Codeplex, whatever, but that's what we're trying to filter for (imperfect as it may be)